# TrustStrategy different certificates than in TrustManagerFactory

Tags: java, apache, ssl, certificate-store

Im looking into TrustStrategy to use in combination with a RestTemplate. Within the isTrusted method, the certificates checked (printed out) are different than the certificates defined in the TrustManagerFactory (certificates printed here are from the cacerts file). Why is this the case? What is happening behind the scenes?

Edit: the isTrusted method logs the certificates of my company. The acceptedIssuers logs the certificates from the cacerts file.

Edit2: The method of the TrustStrategy is called run time. The certificates of the TrustManagerFactory are called compile time. Maybe this is part of the problem/solution.

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
            for (X509Certificate certificate: x509Certificates) {
                log.info(certificate.getIssuerX500Principal().getName());
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    X509Certificate[] acceptedIssuers = trustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();

    for(X509Certificate ai : acceptedIssuers) {
        log.info(ai.getIssuerX500Principal().getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself! So what I misunderstood that the certificates logged by in the isTrusted method of the TrustStrategy are the client certificates. In fact, these are the certificates returned by the server (and therefore only loggable at runtime). The certificates in the TrustManagerFactory are from the cacerts file and are the Client trusted certificates.